# Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to show the posts of my json output into my view but I'm getting an error.

`Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []`

I did some research and it looks like I'm looping a loop which causes Angular to "crash" before my browser does. But I can't find the error in my code.

This is my home state and if I comment out the line `return post.getAll();` I don't get the error, obviously.

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_home.html.haml',
  controller: 'mainCtrl',
  resolve: {
    postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
      return posts.getAll();
    }]
  }
})
```

The getAll(); is referenced here in my service.

```
.factory('posts', [
  '$http',
    function(){
      var o = {
       };
      return o;

      o.getAll = function() {
        return $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data){
          angular.copy(data, o.posts);
        });
      };
    }
])
```

So I think the error should be in one of these codes, any ideas?

I have 2 templates that I include,

posts.html.haml

```
%div{"ng-repeat" => "comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'"}
  {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
  %span{:style => "font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;"}
    {{comment.body}}

%form{"ng-submit" => "addComment()"}
  %h3 Add a new comment
  .form-group
    %input.form-control{"ng-model" => "body", :placeholder => "Comment", :type => "text"}
  %button.btn.btn-primary{:type => "submit"} Post

%a{"ui-sref" => "home"} Home
```

And home.html.haml

```
%form{"ng-submit" => "addPost()"}
  %input{:type => "text", "ng-model" => "title"}
  %button{:type => "submit"} Post

%h1
  Posts
%div{"ng-repeat" => "post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'"}
  {{ post.title }} - upvotes: {{ post.upvotes }}
  %a{:href => "#/posts/{{$index}}"} Comments
```

I've commented both files, and still the error is given.

Comment: there is probably an error in your view. like a nested ng-repeat or something which causes a digest cycle to recur more then 10 times.
could you add the code of the template?

Comment: @MoLow I've added the template code, but that's not the problem. When I comment out all the haml code it still gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that `return o;` in the service should be in the bottom of the file.